# o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application startup failed

Tags: spring-boot

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controller' defined in file [F:\暑期课程设计\data-selecting-system\dbanalysis\target\classes\cn\sunnie\dbanalysis\controller\controller.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [cn.sunnie.dbanalysis.controller.controller]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/ListOrderedMap
```

I add something like map and JSONObject and the result turned out to be things like this>
I don't know what happened because I am a freshman to this field.
Could you please help me to find out where the problem is?
thx~

Answer (score 0):

Last part of your error message points to the source of the problem:

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/ListOrderedMap
```

[`ListOrderedMap<K,V>`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/ListOrderedMap.html) is missing in your classpath. This class is a part of [`commons-collections4`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1) library - add it to your `pom.xml` (if you use Maven) or `build.gradle` (if you use Gradle), refresh dependencies and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help